# How to scale div widths either side of a non-scaling div

Tags: css, scaling

I'd like to be able to keep the width of the center element here non-scaling, while scaling the width of the left and right elements:

telodesign.com/images/stack-example.png

The thing is, I'd really like to keep the images on left and right at 100% of actual size (i.e. not scaling the size down... only the viewable area). So as you have a narrower width browser window, you'd see less and less horizontal areas of those images.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you explain a little more in detail. Slightly confused on what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: The top area has three boxes, each containing an image. There's the iPhone (main-left), the logo/valve (main-center) and the map (home-right). I'd ideally like to keep the main-center box from scaling at all, and then have the left and right boxes maintain the images at 100% within, but scale their widths as needed when the browser is narrower, simply displaying less of the images within. Sorry--I can maybe do a wireframe if that helps. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah I think a little image displaying what you want to achieve would be best. That way I can help far better :)

Comment: Here's what I mean... as you bring the browser window in narrower, the outer boxes scale, though without scaling the image inside. The center box remains unchanged: http://telodesign.com/images/stack-example.png Thanks again!

Comment: Are you currently using any media queries?

Comment: Yes, though what I'm concerned about is happening even before the first media query comes into play. Imagine there are no media queries at all--it's the scaling of the left and right boxes (while maintaining the images within) that I'm hoping to achieve.